# How do people know that their experiment follows a gamma distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, gamma-distribution

I am currently taking a Probability and Statistics course and learning the gamma function. Problems are usually phrased like "A group of scientists did x experiment and it followed a gamma distribution (...)" but I am wondering how do they know? Especially since the gamma function shape varies a lot depending on the values.

Comment: Gamma distribution emerges naturally in phenomena that follow the laws of the Poisson process.

Comment: @YJT so you mean that whenever we have an experiment with an event that happens  on average x times every y interval then gamma distribution will occur naturally?

Comment: The same way you can use a linear regression model and take a high correlation coefficient to suspect with reasonable certainty that the linear equation models the true data.

Comment: @MatthewDaly the case you are talking about is way simpler imho, do they first suspect it is a gamma distribution based on the shape and try to find values of alpha and beta by trial and error?

Comment: That's not exactly the definition, but yes. For example, we know that radioactive elements emerge particles according to a Poisson process with some parameters. The time between turning on the equipment and detecting the first particle follows an exponential distribution. The time until the $n$th particle is already gamma (gamma=sum of exp).

Comment: You can Google "gamma regression" to see the actual process, but it is not trial-and-error.

Comment: Thank you everyone!